# Restore DataBase error - RESTORE HEADERONLY terminated abnormally

Tags: sql-server, ssms

i'm getting this error when i'm trying to restore a database with a .bak extension file.

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

An exception occurred while executing a batch or Transact-SQL statement. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :

The media family on media '****.bak' is incorrect. SQL Server cannot process it.
RESTORE HEADERONLY terminated abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3241)
```

Any help and thanks.

Comment: Make sure the backup was taken on the same or earlier version of SQL Server. You cannot restore a later SQL Server backup to an earlier version.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks but it is the same version

Comment: The above implies that you tried the restore through the GUI. What is the actual restore statement being run (there should be a "Script..." button in the upper left corner of that dialog)? Does it match your expectations?